# Reshape potentially very large 1D-array into multidimensional matrix with variable dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, reshape

I have to postprocess data from a parametric analysis which has as output a 1D-array with the results. 
I would like to reshape this 1D array into a multidimensional matrix which has the dimensions of my investigated parameters (to be in the right order), **and those dimensions may vary in number**.

I could came up with a function based on for-loops, but the problem is that with very large arrays I run out of RAM. I am perfectly aware that this is not the smartest way to do this.
I was wondering if there is a smarter way to manipulate such a large array and to do the same job as my function does.

```
function [Tensor, n_dimensions]=reshape_array(Data,ndim)

n_dimensions=length(ndim);
n_elements=prod(ndim);

reshape_string=[];
for i=n_dimensions:-1:1
    if i==1
    reshape_string=strcat(reshape_string, ' ndim(', num2str(i) , ')])'); 
    elseif i== n_dimensions
    reshape_string=strcat(reshape_string, ' [ndim(', num2str(i) , ')'); 
    else
    reshape_string=strcat(reshape_string, ' ndim(', num2str(i) , ') '); 
    end

end

invert_string=[];
for i=1:n_dimensions
    if i==1
    invert_string=strcat(invert_string, 'ndim(', num2str(i) , '),'); 
    elseif i== n_dimensions
    invert_string=strcat(invert_string, ' ndim(', num2str(i) , ')'); 
    else
    invert_string=strcat(invert_string, ' ndim(', num2str(i) , '),'); 
    end

end

reshape_statement=strcat('reshape(Data,',reshape_string);
invert_statement=strcat('zeros(',invert_string,');');

Tens1=eval(reshape_statement);
Tens2=eval(invert_statement);

nLoops=length(ndim);
str = '';
str_dim_tens='';
str_dim_indeces='';
for i=1:nLoops
    str = strcat(sprintf('%s \n for i%d=1:',str,i), sprintf('%d',ndim(i)));
    if i<nLoops
    str_dim_tens=strcat(str_dim_tens,'i',num2str(i),',');
    else
    str_dim_tens=strcat(str_dim_tens,'i',num2str(i));
    end
end

for i=nLoops:-1:1
    if i~=1
    str_dim_indeces=strcat(str_dim_indeces,'i',num2str(i),',');
    else
    str_dim_indeces=strcat(str_dim_indeces,'i',num2str(i));
    end
end

str = strcat(sprintf('%s \n Tens2(%s)=Tens1(%s);',str,str_dim_tens,str_dim_indeces));

for i=1:nLoops
    str = sprintf('%s \n end',str);
end

eval(str)

Tensor=Tens2;

end
```

as an example,

```
ndim=[2 3];
Data=1:2*3
[Tensor, n_dimensions]=reshape_array(Data,ndim);

n_dimensions =

     2

Tensor =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
```

I would work with more dimensions (e.g. minimum 4) and Data arrays with millions of elements. An example could be M(10,10,10,300000)
This is why I was looking for the least computationally expensive method to do the job.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code, you want to fill the elements in the reshaped array using a dimension order which is the opposite of Matlab's [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) default; that is, you start from the last dimenson, then the second last, etc.

This can be done by reshaping into an array with the dimensions in reverse order (using [`reshape`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html)) and the reversing the order of dimensions back (using [`permute`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html)).

```
n_dimensions = numel(ndim);
Tensor = reshape(Data, ndim(end:-1:1)); % reshape with dimensions in reverse order
Tensor = permute(Tensor, n_dimensions:-1:1); % reverse back order of dimensions
```

Comment: Is a cell really necessary? Doesn't reshape accept an array as shape input?

Comment: Good point! I think so, yes. I'll edit it later, now I have to run. Or edit it yourself it you feel like  :-)

Comment: smarter,faster,shorter. Thanks!